# Line counting - how to exclude a folder?

Tags: bash

I'm using bash to count my lines of source in a project. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*.java' | xargs wc -l
find . -name '*.xml' | xargs wc -l
```

I want to exclude files from the ./gen folder. I think it's something to do with 'prune', but I can't figure out how to do it.

**EDIT**
Thankyou to ruakh, but his code wasn't my final solution, I had to make it count the lines again. Here's the finished thing if anybody wants it:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -path ./gen -prune -o -name '*.java' | xargs wc -l
find . -name '*.xml' | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: works too if pass the find result to grep -v 'regex'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't make ruakh's solution work and ended up with the following instead:

```
find . -not -path '*/gen*' -a \( -name '*.java' -o -name '*.xml' \)
```

Also found an interesting `egrep` option based on GNU find:

```
find a/ -regextype egrep -not -path '*/gen*' -a -regex '.*(java|xml)$'
```

In order to count lines in the matched files you can stick `xargs cat | wc -l` on the end:

```
find . -not -path '*/gen*' -a \( -name '*.java' -o -name '*.xml' \) | xargs cat | wc -l
```

Comment: Thankyou, this seems to be a more complete answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This command:

```
find . -path ./gen -prune -o -name '*.java' -print
```

will print the paths to all `*.java` files that are somewhere inside `.`, minus those that are somewhere inside `./gen`.

Comment: can you help me out with this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527621/how-to-maximize-the-sum