# How to maximize the sum?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, implementation

We are given a sorted array.

Let the initial value of `pass` be zero.

We can do the following operation any number of times:

1. Select any `k` numbers at a time. Add them all up. Add this sum to `pass`
2. If a number, say `x`, is being selected for the *first time* from the array, then it is considered as `x` only. When it is selected for the *second time*, then it is considered as `-x` , and for the third time, again as `x`, and so on...

For example, let the array be `[-14, 10, 6, -6, -10, -10, -14]` and `k = 4`, and we'll only do the operation once. We select these 4 numbers: `{14, 10, 6, -6}`. Adding them up, we get `24`. Then, `pass=pass+24`. Therefore, maximum value of pass is `24`.

How to obtain the maximum value of `pass`?

Comment: For homework-type questions, please see [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/11384392) on how to ask them. Specifically, provide information on what you have already tried and supply a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My second point still stands

Comment: If there are no limit to number of operations, the maximum sum might be obtained after endless additions.

Comment: No.Your logic isn't correct.Finite number of moves will suffice .

Comment: @Firexsecred That sounds as if you already have a solution. Is that the case?

Comment: Yup,I do have. I am here to confirm if I'm right, This is really an easy problem.

Comment: @Firexsecred Can you elaborate on how does finite number of moves will always give you the maximum sum?

Comment: Say,you select '2', add it. Now, when, you select 2 again, its -2; now, 2-2=0; now, doing this infinite times will give us zero or 2, we'll go with +2 :-)

Comment: You could select different windows of k.

Comment: see the answer and the explanation in the comments of the answer :-)

Comment: @גלעדברקן   I've solved this problem, thanks for you checking out. Actually, I was creating this problem because I wanted to add it in a future competition :-)

Comment: @Firexsecred What I find is that, you have accepted an answer which is wrong for many cases. It would be nice if you provide a good answer to this question of yours. Or else it's of no use posting on this site.

Comment: @Resorcinol Nope, that answer is 100% correct, can you show me a case where it goes wrong except when k=n?

Comment: @Firexsecred For 4 4 2 -1 -1 -3, and k=5? What is the answer? It is not 10. It it is show me how?

Comment: Answer is 10 only :-) I am writing the explanation in next comment :-)

Comment: Answer is 10 only :-) I am writing the explanation in next comment :-)

Comment: We select: {4,4,2,-1,-3}......these 5 numbers.....sum is 6, therefore,pass=6 ; agree ? then:--->new array looks like this:-->{-4,-4,-2,-1,1,3}....now select:-{-4,-4,-2,-1,1}.....sum=-10; now pass=6-10=-4; now.....the new array,looks like:-{4,4,2,1,-1,3}.....select:-{4,4,2,1,3}===>sum===>14; therefore, pass=14-4=10 :-)Hope everything is clear now! :-)

Comment: @Firexsecred Really good question man, well framed. But how would you interpret zeros in your array?

Comment: Consider zeroes as positive numbers in your code :-)

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://www.codechef.com/AVEN2019/problems/AVN002/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reformulate the problem as follows:

We have a list of numbers and we can activate or deactivate the numbers. We want to find the maximum sum of activated numbers, where in each pass we can switch exactly `k` numbers.

For odd `k`, we could do the following: Activate the maximum number (if it is positive) and use the remaining `(k-1)` switches to switch any number twice, which will effectively leave the number in its previous state. Therefore, the maximum `pass` value is the sum of positive numbers.

For even `k`, this is slightly different since the number of activated numbers is always even. Therefore, we first find all positive numbers. Let the number of positive numbers be `p`. If `p` is even, then we are good and the sum of these numbers is the result. If `p` is odd, we have to check two cases: Remove the smallest positive number or add the largest non-positive number. The maximum of these two cases is the result.

Edit from comments:

For the special case where `k=n`, there are only two options: Either include all numbers or exclude all numbers. If the sum of numbers is greater than 0, this is the result. Otherwise, the result is 0.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194792/discussion-on-answer-by-nico-schertler-how-to-maximize-the-sum).